# Можно ли связать пуш-нотификации с аналитикой в Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, уведомления, firebaseanalytics

Есть задача реализовать пуш-нотификации Firebase для Android и iOS для пользователей которые не были активны в приложении 7 дней. Можно ли это сделать использовав данные из аналитики Firebase? Если да - то как?

Comment: Вы же знаете, что для отправки Push Notifications нужен свой сервер? Вот этот сервер также может получать данные из аналитики, и на их основании решать кому и когда отправлять пуши.

Comment: @eugeneek  понял спасибо!